# How to insert the value of TextField into TableView in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, tableview

¿Is it possible to insert TextField value into TableView? I would like to insert in "columnCantidad" the value of a TextField. It seems that the field "cantidad" has to exist in a class.

```
@FXML
private TableView<AbstractConcepto> tablaFactura;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Producto, String> columnReferencia;
@FXML
private TableColumn<AbstractConcepto, String> columnDescripcion;
@FXML
private TableColumn<AbstractConcepto, Float> columnCantidad;
@FXML
private TableColumn<AbstractConcepto, Float> columnPrecioUnitario;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Float, Float> columnPrecioTotal;

@Override
public void mostrarDetalle(Servicio servicio, Producto producto) 
{
    if(servicio == null)
    {
        conceptoData.add(producto);
    }
    if(producto == null)
    {
        conceptoData.add(servicio);
    }       

    tablaFactura.setItems(conceptoData);

    return;
}


   private void inicializarTabla()
{
    conceptoData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    columnReferencia.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Producto, String>("codigo"));
    columnDescripcion.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AbstractConcepto, String>("nombre"));
    columnCantidad.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AbstractConcepto, Float>("cantidad"));
    columnPrecioUnitario.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AbstractConcepto, Float>("pvp"));

    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? The text field contains a single value. The column contains a whole list of values. Do you want to add a new row in the table (if so, what goes in the other columns in that new row)? Or do you want to update an existing value?

Comment: I would like to add a new row in the table. In the other columns goes values of "Producto" and "Servicio" fields. But "quantity" is a textField and i would like to insert that value in one column.